# MySQL query to return JSON data is taking a very long time

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am trying to run a query to extract some JSON data from a MySQL table but it's taking a very long time. I ran the query and it still hadn't returned after more than 1 hour. The AWS terminal window timed out by then.

This is what the table looks like:

mytable1

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| m_id             | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| t_id             | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp        | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |   
| mydata           | json         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

mydata column has json data like this:

```
{
    "var1": "adfsfs",
    "var2": "dafdafds",
    "abc1": {
        "vals": {
            "x1": 11,
            "yz": [4,3,5,5]
        }
    }
}
```

This is the query:

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(mydata,'$.abc1') from mytable1 where timestamp=1627003989;
```

There are less than 90,000 rows in the table. Each row is only about 1 MB most of which is in the "mydata" field.

There is only one index - on the m_id field.

Any idea why this is taking so long? Is there some other way I could extract data from that json column?

Comment: How many records have that timestamp value? How long does it take to return `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mytable1 WHERE timestamp=1627003989`?

Comment: Just under 90,000 records since each record has one timestamp associated with it. 
That query takes less than 0.5 second.

Comment: 1MB per row is pretty large. That's ~90GB of data, plus the time it takes to parse the records and extract the key you want

Comment: What I don't understand is that even if I don't use JSON_EXTRACT and instead just say: 
```select * from mytable1 where timestamp=1627003989```, it takes forever. That shouldn't even be doing any parsing of the JSON data, right? All that should do is look at the timestamp for a match and return the whole record.

Comment: If there's no index on the `timestamp` column, then it has to do a table-scan, examining every row. That means pulling 90GB off of disk into the buffer pool, before it even starts to extract the field you want from the JSON documents. That's probably the majority of time spent, much more costly than the JSON extraction.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I appreciate it. Just before seeing your answer, I added an index on timestamp based on some other article I saw and that made the difference. Less than 1 sec now to run the query.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on the timestamp column.